# TypeError: listen is not a function

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm not sure if is an issue or maybe there is a change between version 2.x and 3.x. When require the socket.io package in the first version I can use a function listen and pass an http server as parameter, but using the 3.x version this function does not exists and throw this TypeError.

This is an issue or something change?

This is the snipet, with the 2.x socket.io version works, but using the latest one doesn't

```
const socketIO = require('socket.io')

let socket;

const connectionSocket = (server) => {
  const io = socketIO.listen(server);

  io.on('connection', (newSocket) => {
    socket = newSocket;
    console.log(newSocket.id);
  });
}

const getSocket = () => socket;

module.exports = {
  connectionSocket,
  getSocket
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write something like this:

```
const server = http.createServer(app);

const setServer = server => {
  io = socketIo(server, { transports: ['websocket', 'polling'] });

  io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.on('user-connection', userConnected(socket));
  });
};
```